# masonry not working as jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

So I installed masonry using npm install.
I'm including it via browserify

```
var $ = require('jquery'),
    masonry = require('masonry-layout');
```

Kinda working ok when using it with native javascript:

```
that.msnry = new Masonry( container[0], {
    columnWidth: 200,
    itemSelector: '.masonry__element',
    gutter: 10
});
```

That seems to initally position my element but after adding new elements to the dom calling:

```
that.msnry.appended( $(el) );
that.msnry('reload');
```

just results in an error:

```
that.msnry is not a function(anonymous function) @ gallery.js:20956emitEvent @ gallery.js:7416emit @ gallery.js:7443(anonymous function) @ gallery.js:6827
```

So then I tried to go down the Jquery route:

```
$('#container').masonry();
```

Not working. Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).masonry is not a function
```

Not sure what's going on here? Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Did you try `that.msnry.reload()`, or `that.msnry.reloadItems()`? ([The documentation](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#reloaditems) doesn't list `reload` as a function.)

Comment: Not sure if you saw this info:  To use Masonry as a jQuery plugin with Browserify, you need to use jQuery Bridget.

Comment: Ok thanks so that helped, the native js .appended(arrayOfAppendedElemens) does something. I guess  I must have been looking at an older version of the docs. The new elements are positioned really far down the screen though. I wonder why masonry is positioning them so weirdly???

Thanks for the jquery tip also, will try and go down the native route first and come back to it if it doesn't work.

Comment: actually all working fine now. Thanks for your help!!!